# Looking up a connecting flight

Tags: mysql, query

Suppose a database has two columns, arrival and destination.

I want to check flights from Miami to Usuhaia. There are two flights I have to take.

```
ARRIVAL | DESTINATION
MIA, EZE
EZE, USH
```

So I would like to query the database for two things:

1. Is this flight possible, or does it exist?
2. What is or are the flights that I would have to take?

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: do you hae mysql 8, there you can use recursive CTE

Comment: Use the database as the source of data, bu leave complicated questions like flight scheduling to the app.

Comment: Execute `SELECT version();` and provide the output.